# Error getting POM for 'org.codehaus.mojo:jasperreports-maven-plugin' from the repository

Tags: maven-2, jasper-reports, jboss7.x

I am trying to deploy OSGI bundle to Jboss 7.1.1.Final. Everytime I compile and deploy project it gives me following error.

I have checked in M2, only 1.0-beta-2 version is present as we can see similar thing mentioned in repository too http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/jasperreports-maven-plugin/1.0-beta-2

There is no version defined in POM, not sure from where it is trying to pull this version.

**Command**
mvn jboss-as:deploy -Pdomain -DskipTests -Dusername=manish -Dpassword=password -Dhost=x.x.x.x -Dport=9999 -X

**POM Configuration**

```
<repository>
            <id>jboss-public-repository</id>
            <name>JBoss Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jasperreports</id>
            <url>http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
        ...
    <plugins>
    <!-- Jasper Plugins -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jasper</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>compile-reports</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
                <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
                <version>4.7.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.5</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
```

**Error**

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Error getting POM for 'org.codehaus.mojo:jasperreports-maven-plugin' from the repository: Failed to resolve artifact, possibly due to a repository list that is not appropriately equipped for this artifact's metadata.
  org.codehaus.mojo:jasperreports-maven-plugin:pom:1.0-beta-3-SNAPSHOT

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
  jboss-public-repository (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public)

 for project org.codehaus.mojo:jasperreports-maven-plugin
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.findModelFromRepository(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:592)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildFromRepository(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:251)
    at org.apache.maven.project.artifact.MavenMetadataSource.retrieveRelocatedProject(MavenMetadataSource.java:163)
    ... 22 more
```

Answer (score 2):

The jasperreport plugin is available via Maven central but not as a SNAPSHOT version. The question is if you need to use the SNAPSHOT version or the release version which can be found [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22org.codehaus.mojo%22%20AND%20a%3a%22jasperreports-maven-plugin%22).

Comment: How do I change configuration to not use SNAPSHOT version and use beta2 as latest version.

Comment: Dont use repositories in your pom which defults to use mavencentral